# How to allow a std:string parameter to be NULL?

Tags: c++, std

I have a function `foo(const std::string& str);` that it does crash if you call it using `foo(NULL)`.

What can I do to prevent it from crashing?

Comment: What are you doing with str inside foo ? If you test for if str is NULL and gracefully exit from the function, it shouldn't crash.

Comment: You have been given some helpful suggestions, but are you sure you are approaching this right? Why are you using a pointer? Part of the beauty of std::string (and references) is that you don't have to mess with the pointer. (Usually)

Comment: This is also the reason for the infamous `std::string s(false)` thing.

Comment: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this!" ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

std::string has a constructor that takes a const char* parameter. That's constructor is going to crash when you pass NULL to it, and that constructor is called implicitly when you write foo(NULL).

The only solution I can think of is to overload foo

```
void foo(const std::string& str)
{
  // your function
}

void foo(const char* cstr)
{
  if (cstr == NULL)
    // do something
  else
     foo(std::string(cstr)); // call regular funciton
}
```

Comment: +1. I deleted my own response after @James McNellis correctly pointed out that I had somehow overlooked the key point ...

Answer (score 8):

You could use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

void func(optional<string>& s) {
    if (s) {  // implicitly converts to bool
        // string passed in
        cout << *s << endl; // use * to get to the string
    } else {
        // no string passed in
    }
}
```

To call it with a string:

```
string s;
func(optional<string>(s));
```

and without a string:

```
func(optional<string>());
```

Boost.Optional gives you a typesafe way to have nullable values without resorting to pointers and their associated problems.

Comment: optional now exists in C++17 as [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Answer (score 1):

You have a function that accepts a `std::string`, so provide it an `std::string`, not a pointer.

```
foo(std::string());
```

This will provide the function with an empty string, which is probably what you would have interpreted your null value as anyhow.