# Initializing strings as null vs. empty string

Tags: c++, string, initialization

Would it matter if my C++ code (as shown below) has a string initialized as an empty string:

```
std::string myStr = "";
....some code to optionally populate 'myStr'...
if (myStr != "") {
    // do something
}
```

vs. no/null initialization:

```
std::string myStr;
....some code to optionally populate 'myStr'...
if (myStr != NULL) {
    // do something
}
```

Are there any concerns here?

Comment: `NULL` (conceptually) is a pointer, and should only be used as such. A `std::string` isn't a pointer, so it shouldn't be combined. PS. the initializations are the same: the ctor of `std::string` sets it to the empty string.

Comment: @MSalters hi I agree to your point but then if the types seems to be incompatible why does the compiler doesn't throw an error. I have VS 2010 and it silently initialize the std::string with NULL.

Comment: @Surfing_SO: There's a string constructor which takes a pointer to an array of characters, terminated by a zero char.. You incorrectly did not pass such a pointer (NULL doesn't point to an array of characters, or anything else). This is Undefined Behavior and anything may happen in that case.

Comment: As both mentioned "NULL" is not exactly the way it is being initialized. The reason your if works is probably because compiler is implicitly converting both sides to bool and then performs the comparison, which is not what you really wanted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow a std:string parameter to be NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884300/how-to-allow-a-stdstring-parameter-to-be-null)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There's a function `empty()` ready for you in `std::string:`

```
std::string a;
if(a.empty())
{
    //do stuff. You will enter this block if the string is declared like this
}
```

or

```
std::string a;
if(!a.empty())
{
    //You will not enter this block now
}
a = "42";
if(!a.empty())
{
    //And now you will enter this block.
}
```

Answer (score 29):

There are no gotchas. The default construction of `std::string` is `""`. But you cannot compare a string to `NULL`. The closest you can get is to check whether the string is empty or not, using the `std::string::empty` method..

Comment: There is extra temporary when constructing `std::string` and assigning `""` to it.

Comment: @vladon I'm not really sure what temporary you're referring to, or how assignment is relevant. I can't see a temporary in `a = "";` when `a` is `std::string`, but the question isn't about that.

Comment: The default construction of `std::string` is not `""`; it is `{}`. Default-constructing avoids having to check the `char const*`, find it is an empty string, and eventually do nothing. That's better.

Answer (score 25):

Best:

```
 std::string subCondition;
```

This creates an empty string.

This:

```
std::string myStr = "";
```

does a copy initialization - creates a temporary string from `""`, and then uses the copy constructor to create `myStr`.

Bonus:

```
std::string myStr("");
```

does a direct initialization and uses the `string(const char*)` constructor.

To check if a string is empty, just use `empty()`.

Comment: would not `std::string myStr = "";` invoke a `string(const char*)` constructor? Why do you think a temporary will be created?

Comment: @Andrew weird, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223285/whats-the-motivation-between-having-copy-and-direct-initialization-behave-diffe

Comment: @Andrew It almost certainly won't be created, since the standard gives the implementations explicit leave not to create it.  On the other hand, the code must be legal even if the temporary was constructed; i.e., there must be an accessible copy constructor.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, but that's an optimization. You can't rely on it. Theoretically, a temp is created.

Comment: Great hint about the empty string initialisation, which is done nearly all the time when people create a new CString. ;)

Answer (score 8):

I would prefere

```
if (!myStr.empty())
{
    //do something
}
```

Also you don't have to write `std::string a = "";`. You can just write `std::string a;` - it will be empty by default

Answer (score 7):

Empty-ness and "NULL-ness" are two different concepts. As others mentioned the former can be achieved via `std::string::empty()`, the latter can be achieved with `boost::optional<std::string>`, e.g.:

```
boost::optional<string> myStr;
if (myStr) { // myStr != NULL
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor initializes the string to the empty string.  This is the more economic way of saying the same thing.

However, the comparison to `NULL` stinks.  That is an older syntax still in common use that means something else; a null pointer.  It means that there is no string around.

If you want to check whether a string (that does exist) is empty, use the `empty` method instead:

```
if (myStr.empty()) ...
```