# Value and size of an uninitialized std::string variable in c++

Tags: c++, stdstring

If a string is defined like this

```
std::string name;
```

What will be the value of the uninitialized string "name" and what size it would be?

Comment: It isn't uninitialized.

Comment: As others have noted, the default constructor has been called, but to answer the specific question, you could try `cout << name` and `cout << name.length()`.

Comment: @Simon trying something doesn't tell you if the behaviour's undefined or implementation defined (but it would have been a good start :-)).

Comment: @TonyD Note, however, that Simon has a point here. How about firing up the documentation? Doesn't even need to come up with sample code for that. (Or, for that matter, this is in every reasonably good beginner C++ guide...)

Comment: @H2CO3: documentation *obviously* - every answer already referenced that; but that point simply isn't made by Simon's comment, and plenty of people do write code with undefined or implementation defined behaviour accidentally because they try the code and it does/seems-to work so they don't look at the documentation.  My comments actually arguing against *not* looking at documentation, indirectly.

Comment: @TonyD: +1. I agree that the practical test doesn't help if the behaviour is undefined or implementation-dependent. In this case, the behaviour was well-defined, but I agree there are plenty of situations where implementation-dependence is an issue. Actually, I'm just dealing with one at the moment in (cringe) Fortran 77 ...

Comment: Coming from Java and C# world, I just kept feeling "unsafe" when seeing definition like that with no default values. But yes, it is actually initialized to empty (`""`) string.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Because it is not initialized, it is the default constructor that is called. Then :

> **empty string constructor (default constructor) :**
>
> Constructs an empty string, with a length of zero characters.

Take a look : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

**EDIT :**
As stated in *C++11, §21.4.2/1* :

> Eﬀects: Constructs an object of class **basic_string**. The postconditions of this function are indicated in Table 63.

```
-> Table 63
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| data()     | a non-null pointer that is copyable and can have 0 added to it |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| size()     | 0                                                              |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| capacity() | an unspeciﬁed value                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 21):

It's not uninitialized, its *default constructor* is called.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string:

> Default constructor. Constructs empty string.

Answer (score 17):

Default constructed user-defined types are not uninitialized. The default constructor defines an empty string (i.e `""`) with a size/length of zero.

Answer (score 5):

The Standard (C++11, §21.4.2/1) describes the results of default-constructing a `std::basic_string` (of which `std::string` is a specialization) as follows:

> [...] an object of class `basic_string`. The postconditions [...] are indicated in Table 63.

And Table 63 says:

> `data()`    a non-null pointer that is copyable and can have 0 added to it
>   `size()` 0
>   `capacity()` an unspecified value

Comment: What is the significance of the "can have 0 added to it" part?  It seems out of the blue.  Can't you add 0 to any non-null pointer?

Comment: @vargonian: That doesn't mean the pointer's value has `0` mathematically added to it. It means the buffer pointed-to by the result of `data()` may have an additional `\0` byte at the end. It's very poor wording.

Comment: @vargonian or even to a null pointer?

Answer (score -9):

value is null , and size is 0
But you can directly chk if the string is empty or not by empty()

Just in case you want to check that in your application , Do this

```
std::string name // Construct an empty string  
if(name.empty()) { // Check if its empty
  name="something";
}
```

Similar and more detailed discussion is here
[initializing strings as null vs. empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556394/initializing-strings-as-null-vs-empty-string)

Comment: This doesn't merely check whether the string is empty. It assigns a value to it. Also, how does this answer the question?