# String class constructor safety

Tags: c++, string

Is the following safe:

```
string s;
s += "dsgdf";
cout << s;
```

Is the string auto initialized with `""` or I need to do this?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17738439/1883647)

Comment: Effectively (but not techincally), if a class has a constructor, then a constructor is always called.  `string` has a constructor, and therefore an instance of `string` has always had a constructor called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A default-constructed string is empty, yes. It's not uninitialized or in some other unsafe state.