# Why is it valid to get string[0] even when it has not been initialized?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider this code

```
string str;
cout << str[0] << str.size();
```

And what I get is not a run time error, but `" 0"`, a `0` following a space. Why is this possible?

Comment: `std::string()` is an empty string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738439/value-and-size-of-uninitialized-stdstring-variable-in-c.

Comment: Also, even if you did something illegal, nothing guarantees that you will get a runtime error.  What you would get is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: This is a gem of a question. Why so few upvotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str` is not uninitialized, it's [default initalized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) as an empty `std::string`; i.e. its `size()` is `0`. And since C++11, the standard requires [std::basic_string::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) to return a reference to the null character for this case.

> If `pos == size()`, a reference to the character with value `CharT()` (the null character) is returned.

It's worth noting that before C++11, for the non-const version of `operator[]` this is undefined behavior, for the const version a reference to null character will be returned; and since C++11 for the non-const version, any modification to other character on the returned reference is undefined behavior.

BTW: [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means anything is possible; it has not to be a runtime error.

Comment: And this is a gem of an answer! I think it's UB to attempt to modify the character through that reference. Is it worth adding that?

Comment: @P45Imminent I think I've mentioned it.. "Since C++11 any modification to other character on the returned reference is undefined behavior."