# C++ - Assigning null to a std::string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, null

I am learning C++ on my own. I have the following code but it gives error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int setvalue(const char * value)
{
    string mValue;
    if(value!=0)
    {
       mValue=value;
    }
    else
    {
       mValue=0;
    }
}

int main ()
{
 const char* value = 0;
 setvalue(value);

 cin.get();
 return 0;
}
```

So want to create a function which accepts char pointers and I want to pass a pointer to it. The function assigns the pointer to its member variable. I'm passing a null pointer intentionally. Following is the error I'm getting:

```
 D:\CPP\TestCP.cpp In function `int setvalue(const char*)': 

 note C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\basic_string.h:422 candidates are: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] 

 note C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\basic_string.h:422                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] 

 note C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\basic_string.h:422                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
```

it's basically complaining about line:   mValue=0;

Why is it complaining about this line? I can't assign a null to a String?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting it to 0?

Comment: The purpose of the function is to take the char* passed to the function and assign it to it's member string variable. So I'm checking first if it is null, if it is null, then instead of dereferencing a null pointer, I'm assigning null to String. So the purpose is to have mValue and Value to contain similar values. Thanks.

Comment: But `mValue = value;` would just do `mValue = 0;` when `value` is a null pointer, if `mValue = 0;` were valid, so the extra check doesn't really do anything. It would be just as invalid.

Comment: You might want to look into `boost::optional` if you're set on distinguishing between an empty string and no string.

Comment: @Maria - You cannot learn C++ by trying it out by yourself, you need [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also gcc 3.4.2 is not a good compiler anymore, it is very old.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow a std:string parameter to be NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884300/how-to-allow-a-stdstring-parameter-to-be-null)

Answer (score 86):

> I can't assign a null to a String?

No.  `std::string` is not a pointer type; it cannot be made "null."  It cannot represent the absence of a value, which is what a null pointer is used to represent.

It can be made *empty*, by assigning an empty string to it (`s = ""` or `s = std::string()`) or by clearing it (`s.clear()`).

Comment: Note that you get the compile error with `NULL` or `0`. However using `nullptr` compiles since it's not an int and the assignment operator for `char*` is chosen. It will error at runtime though.

Answer (score 20):

You cannot assign `NULL` or `0` to a C++ `std::string` object, because the object is not a pointer.  This is one key difference from C-style strings; a C-style string can either be `NULL` or a valid string, whereas C++ `std::string`s always store some value.

There is no easy fix to this.  If you'd like to reserve a sentinel value (say, the empty string), then you could do something like

```
const std::string NOT_A_STRING = "";

mValue = NOT_A_STRING;
```

Alternatively, you could store a pointer to a string so that you can set it to null:

```
std::string* mValue = NULL;

if (value) {
    mValue = new std::string(value);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: mValue=new std::string(value); gives error: 11 D:\CPP\TestCP.cpp invalid conversion from `std::string*' to `char' 11 D:\CPP\TestCP.cpp   initializing argument 1 of `std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'

Comment: @Maria- Did you change the declaration of `mValue` from `string myValue` to `string* myValue`?

Comment: no, I don't want it to be a pointer. Can I do this: minValue = (char*)0 ?

Comment: @Maria: No you cannot.  It is undefined behavior.  What would you expect it to mean anyway?  You've already been told you can't have a null string.

Answer (score 7):

Literal `0` is of type `int` and you can't assign `int` to `std::string`. Use `mValue.clear()` or assign an empty string `mValue=""`.

Comment: Not that you aren't right, but that doesn't explain what's wrong.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work; NULL might be used as a sentinel here.  C strings let you distinguish between empty and NULL strings; C++ strings don't.

Comment: empty string and null are not the same. I can't assign Null to string?

Comment: @Maria: No, `0` is of type `int`, but empty string literal `""` is of type `char const *` (a pointer to constant char). That are two completely different types.

Comment: @JurajBlaho, It's a `const char[]`, actually.

Comment: @chris: True. Anyway it can be implicitly converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

There are two methods to consider which achieve the same effect for handling null pointers to C-style strings.

The ternary operator

```
void setvalue(const char *value)
{
    std::string mValue = value ? value : "";

}
```

or the humble if statement

```
void setvalue(const char *value)
{
    std::string mValue;
    if(value) mValue = value;

}
```

In both cases, `value` is only assigned to `mValue` when `value` is *not* a null pointer.  In all other cases (i.e. when `value` *is* null), `mValue` will contain an empty string.

The ternary operator method may be useful for providing an alternative default string literal in the absence of a value from `value`:

```
std::string mValue = value ? value : "(NULL)";
```

Comment: To be clear, the reason to check for null and conditionally assign like this is because initialising/assigning an `std::string` from a null pointer causes undefined behaviour and thus should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @underscore_d Awesome comment. You saved my day. :)

Answer (score 5):

I won't argue that it's a *good* idea (or the semantics of using `nullptr` with things that aren't *pointers*), but it's relatively simple to create a class which would provide "[nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)" semantics (see [nullable_string](http://ideone.com/nYJR5M)).

However, this is a much better fit for C++17's [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

// optional can be used as the return type of a factory that may fail
std::optional<std::string> create(bool b)
{
    if (b)
        return "Godzilla";
    else
        return {};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "create(false) returned "
              << create(false).value_or("empty") << std::endl;

    // optional-returning factory functions are usable as conditions of while and if
    if (auto str = create(true))
    {
        std::cout << "create(true) returned " << *str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`std::optional`, as shown in the example, is convertible to `bool`, or you may use the `has_value()` method, has exceptions for bad access, etc. This provides you with nullable semantics, which seems to be what [Maria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1546511/maria) was trying to accomplish.

And if you don't want to wait around for C++17 compatibility, [see this answer about Boost.Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884585/1136311).

Answer (score 1):

The `else` case is unncecessary, when you create a `string` object it is empty by default.

Answer (score 0):

compiler gives error because when assigning mValue=0 compiler find assignment operator=(int ) for compile time binding but it's not present in the string class.
if we type cast following statement to char like mValue=(char)0 then its compile successfully because string class contain operator=(char) method.

Answer (score -1):

Many C APIs use a null pointer to indicate "use the default", e.g. [mosquittopp](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html). Here is the pattern I am using, based on [David Cormack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050744/david-cormack)'s answer:

```
    mosqpp::tls_set(
        MqttOptions->CAFile.length() > 0 ? MqttOptions->CAFile.c_str() : NULL,
        MqttOptions->CAPath.length() > 0 ? MqttOptions->CAPath.c_str() : NULL,
        MqttOptions->CertFile.length() > 0 ? MqttOptions->CertFile.c_str() : NULL,
        MqttOptions->KeyFile.length() > 0 ? MqttOptions->KeyFile.c_str() : NULL
    );
```

It is a little cumbersome, but allows one to keep everything as a `std::string` up until the API call itself.

Comment: You could very easily add an inlined utility method to accomplish the same.  `char const* c_str(std::string const &s) { return s.length() > 0 ? s.c_str() : nullptr; }`  Usage:  `mosqpp::tls_set(c_str(MqttOptions->CAFile), c_str(MqttOptions->CAPath), c_str(MqttOptions->CertFile), c_str(MqttOptions->KeyFile));`