# Is there any difference between the different methods of clearing the contents of a string variable?

Tags: c++

Given a string variable set to some value:

`string s = "Hello";`

Is there any difference (performance, gotchas) between the following methods to clear the contents?:

`s = ""`

`s = std::string()`

`s.clear()`

I got the sample code from this answer to a question about clearing a variable https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617595/1228532

Comment: although the code behind may be different for the 3, I see no performance deifference ot special gotchas between them.

Comment: It depends on whether you want to hold on to the allocated memory or discard that, too.

Comment: I _think_ the rule should be that if a class provides a sensible defined clear/truncate/etc method, that should be preferred to anything that involves assignment/temporaries/copyctors or such.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some noticeable differences.

`clear` sets the length of the string to 0, but does *not* change its capacity.

`s=""` or `s = std::string()` creates a whole new (empty) string, assigns its value to the existing string, and throws away the contents of the existing string. Especially if you're using an implementation of `std::string` that doesn't include the short string optimization, this may well be much slower than `clear`. To add insult to injury, it also means that if you add more data to the string, it'll end up reallocating the buffer starting from a tiny buffer that it will probably have to reallocate as the string grows.

Bottom line: `clear` will often be faster, not to mention giving a...clear expression of your real intent.